# rails how can i build navigation from database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, menu

how are you building menus from database ? 
Like Category menu where every Category can be in other Category (submenus)
I look that simple-navigation is popular, but i never done that, can some of you please post some example of your code or how i can do that ? thank you

Comment: acts_as_tree along with a content model and/or field as part of the navigation model.

Comment: Hello thank you but how i can use acts_as_tree for showing navigation for example in simple-navigation ? i dont have to use that gem i only need any navigation at all :p i can do simple write it in PHP but in Rails i really have no clue